# View new questions marked with any of your 'interesting tags'

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching

Is there a page that shows questions marked with **any** of your interesting tags?

eg if I have three related tags, say [poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poi), [poi-hssf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poi-hssf), [hwpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hwpf) (on SO) how can I view the newest questions from any of these tags in the one list?

Comment: This is, IMHO, the most important feature yet unimplemented in the system.

Comment: The Unanswered/my tags filter is close, but is limited to "questions with no upvoted answers".  I want to see *all* questions with any of my tags, upvoted answers or not.

Comment: Vote this feature-request up also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Answer (score 3):

Right now you would have to clear out your entire interesting tags list and then fill it back up with those three (3) tags you're interested in.

> [select your tags http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/6171/interesttagshog.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/6171/interesttagshog.png)

Then click for **Unanswered**  and then select the **My Tags** tab.

> [move to the tabs http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/6366/mytagshog.png](http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/6366/mytagshog.png)

That will show up all questions (but only those without an answer that has received any upvotes) with any and either of your selected tags.

But right now if you tried something like this in the search:

> **`[poi]`** or **`[poi-hssf]`** or **`[hwpf]`**

It would return all questions tagged with the trio. Not those with just the one or two, but all three.

You would net nothing.

> [image: dance off to zero]

Comment: Will this actually work?  The 'My Tags' tooltip states that its tags that you have been active in, not your favorites tags.

Comment: Having never answered any phpdoc questions, but seeing it on the My Tags would suggest so.

Comment: You asked for it! :)

Comment: Now **that** is how you edit someone else's post.

Comment: Yes! And I can do even worse!

Comment: Seems to work for me too.  Perhaps its time for a tooltip update.

Comment: More than likely the tags in your interested list are ones you're most active in. So the tooltip still works.

Comment: wow - i've never seen such nicely illustrated answers to a question before. all jon skeet does is type - boring. Thanks for pointing out the 'my tags' part of unanswered - that's not really what I need but I think it's the closest built-in feature at the moment.
Is it just me, or should the suggested search [poi] or [poi-hssf] or [hwpf] get the job done? Is 'or' broken?

Comment: OR is kind of ignored in the search. It's implicit for words, but if you have tags in the search, they are ANDed into the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to be able to view a page with recent questions with any of my preferred tags. Else it's a bother to go to the page for each tag and skim, then move to the next tag. This would make jumping in to any of the sites much quicker.

Comment: Grant, go  vote for this feature request then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Answer (score 0):

try search by tags like this:
[php][or][mysql][or][jquery], where php, mysql, jquery is your favorite tags