# How to see newest questions for all of interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-users, tag-watching

Is there a way to see all newest or unanswered questions in interesting tags defined by user ?

Currently I am able to see newest question for only one tag but not for all of my interested tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [View new questions marked with any of your ‘interesting tags’](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Click the "My Tags" tab on the Unanswered page to see unanswered questions in your interesting tags.

Additionally, click the "related" tags on the right hand column of the page to create tag combinations (a+b, a+b+c, etc).

Beyond that see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/