# Can I filter all questions by my favorite tags?

Tags: support, questions, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)
>   [View new questions marked with any of your 'interesting tags'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags)

How I can filter all newest questions by my favorite tags only?

Comment: It's intresting, but i can search by tags from search query string with query like this:
[php][or][mysql][or][jquery] and it works! I see all questions with my tags :)