# is there a way to see 'newest' questions 'in my tags'?

Tags: feature-request, questions, my-tags

I'd like to be able to watch the newest questions coming in, but only the questions that have one of my interesting tags on it.

Essentially, I want a combination of [sort=newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) and [tab=mytags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags)

Or does this already exist, and I'm just missing it?

**clarification:** I'm wanting to see new questions with any of my tags, whether or not they have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) for the dupe.

Comment: Yep, pretty much an exact dupe.

Comment: Oh, heh.  Just noticed who asked that question. ;)

Comment: :) It made it easy to find.