# Feature Request : "My tags" Filter in all pages && Bug : Sort not working in my tags

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, my-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List newest questions only matching my interesting tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/list-newest-questions-only-matching-my-interesting-tags)

Hi,

**My Tags** is a nice feature which filters & shows the posts by my interesting tags. But this  filter only implemented in **Unanswerd** posts.

It would be really great if the feature is implemented in all the pages . Instead of having a  seperate My tags tab, we could have my tags button in all the pages (in right pane, to filter & show  only my interesting tags)

And there is another one bug in "My Tags" tab, this feature doesn't sort the posts by the latest activity or a date.

this is mytags page
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3d370e8378.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3d370e8378.jpg)

I just opened the first post, check the last activity details.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c1ce035adf.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c1ce035adf.jpg)

Cheers

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/list-newest-questions-only-matching-my-interesting-tagsc http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22288/is-there-a-way-to-see-newest-questions-in-my-tags

Comment: IE6? I shall go burn out my eyes now.