# Is there a way to sort unanswered "my tag" questions by date, newest first?

Tags: feature-request, search, my-tags, tag-search

How do I sort questions in the "my tags" tab of the `Unanswered` section of Stack Overflow by date, with the newest first?

Or, at least, how can I show only interesting tags, ordered by date, newest first?

Comment: It's sorted by vote.

Comment: yeah most voted can be rather annoying. I want to see the newest ones.

Comment: This would be an extemely useful feature. Unfortunately, a request for this feature was declined earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Answer (score 7):

I've written a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/66416) answering the second question. It substitutes interesting tags into  in the following url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=<tags>&sort=newest`

Comment: interesting.  you should add this into the great greasemonkey script thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations

Comment: this solution doesn't quite work for me as it also lists tags that are not in my tag list

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a way to do exactly what you describe and I found this.
Check out StackExchange filters as described in Jeff's following reply:

> [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags/101575#101575)

This filter will allow you to follow unanswered questions with your favorite tags by most recent date on all StackExchange sites!
Or you can change the default filter to target only StackOverflow.

Comment: +1, This actually works for **showing only unanswered** questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this, but not by using the unanswered tab, instead use an advanced search with intags set to "mine" and specifying answers of 0:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3Amine+answers%3A0