# how do I run a userscript?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, sorting, userscript

I was going to ask how to see unanswered questions with my tags sorted newest first but found it already [asked and answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/sorting-unanswered-my-tag-questions-newest-first).  Except I'm not familiar with userscripts.org and have no idea how to run them.  How do I run the [script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/66416) mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/sorting-unanswered-my-tag-questions-newest-first/35570#35570)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on your browser. In Firefox, you need the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) extension installed. Then just hit the install button on the web-page for the script of your choice.

This is all [explained](http://userscripts.org/about/installing) on the userscripts site itself.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  Funny, I had looked on userscripts.org but there is no "about" or "install" link on their main pages.

Comment: odd that it makes NO mention of Chrome which has [native support for Greasemonkey scripts](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html) as of version 4.