# Color code favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

It would be nice to be able to color code the highlighting of favorite tags.  This way I can set all my tag:asp.net tags to blue, my php tags to green, and my database tags to red.

This helps you find questions and categorize them visually.  Now, I just see a sea of orange, and while it does help me to ignore tags I'm not interested in, I'd like something a little cleaner.

Comment: So write yourself up a userscript that does it and share it with Meta. I'm sure you're not the only one who would use it.

Comment: @Whom - I have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: Userscripts are scripts that can be defined to run against specific webpages or entire domains that allow for client-side manipulation of page content and layout. In other words, you have all the tools you need to do this yourself, because that's the only way you're going to get this feature.

Comment: @Whom - I still have no idea what you're referring to. I know of no such functionality built into stack overflow.

Comment: The functionality is built into your browser, not into Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mystere, I've never bothered to run a userscript myself, but if you want to try, [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49800/how-do-i-run-a-userscript) might help get you going.

Comment: I don't use Chrome or Firefox.  I see no way to do this in IE.

Comment: @Whom - no, the functionality is not built in to my browser.  You seem to be referring to plug-ins for Firefox, the whole world doesn't use FF, i'm sure you're aware.

Comment: Well, yeah. Firefox sucks. Use Chrome, it's the best.

Comment: @Whom - If the site shouldn't provide features that can be hacked together by the users, should we petition for removal of http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/all.css ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, Farray.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow custom colorization of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/allow-custom-colorization-of-tags)

Comment: Also, oh no! This would interfere with my [existing feature request](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/209?m=135379#135379).

Comment: [I maed a script with colours in it](http://stackapps.com/questions/3230/color-tags-script)

Answer (score 3):

This would be a nice feature, even if SO assigned the colors I wouldn't complain.  But I'm tired of opening my page to have EVERY single question highlighted in the same color.

Answer (score 1):

There was a lot of talk about an extension, so I made a google extension, I also see that [H.B. made a stack exchange plug in that color codes the tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/3230/color-tags-script), this color codes the whole line.  It colors it based on the first matching tag.

I plan to eventaully add a dialog for picking tags, and their colors.

[color changer extenstion](http://theinfluence.net/colorImportantQs.crx)

You cant install it from the link, see here how to:
http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning