# Prioritising certain tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

For me, tags do not merely fall into 3 categories: favourite, not-favourite or do-not-want. Some tags are *more interesting* to me than others. I am a Scala developer; I don't develop in Java on a regular basis (or ever, really, any more). I do help answer Java questions because I know the language and many of them are not language-specific, and there aren't very many Scala questions by comparison to the number of Java questions.

But when a Scala question does appear, I'd like it to float to the top of the list.

There are one or two other "super-interesting" topics for which I feel the same.

Of course I can and do scan questions by eye, but I would like the site to help me out here.

Yes, I can subscribe to tags by email, and in the case of Scala, I can follow the Scala tag on Twitter. Nevertheless, I would appreciate being able to sort questions by how interesting their tags are to me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I guess [this Google Chrome extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148464/153018) which colour-codes questions by tag, would be a good enough workaround for now. It doesn't sort them, but it would make it easier to scan by eye.