# How to search for unanswered questions, in my tags only, newest first

Tags: support, search

I want to search for:

- unanswered questions
- only in my tags
- sorted by newest first

I'd have guessed this was very common—if not the default.  However I can't figure it out.  Closest I can find on meta is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/sorting-unanswered-my-tag-questions-newest-first), which doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: Duplicate of the one you linked (whats the difference to your question?) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/57564

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting unanswered 'my tag' questions newest first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/sorting-unanswered-my-tag-questions-newest-first)

Comment: @Sfinnie, make sure and upvote the feature-request you linked to let them know that you want it implemented.

Comment: thx all.  Have upvoted feature request.  Don't understand why Jeff's resisting - but hey, it's his site :-)

Comment: I updated my answer to show unanswered, sorry for missing that.

Comment: When you say "only in my tags," you mean not specific tags, but all your tags, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the search I use, just replace the bold with your tags,it works fine for a few tags:

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=**[excel]**%20**[vba]**%20answers%3a0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[excel]%20[vba]%20answers%3a0)

Comment: I don't see `unanswered` in there...

Comment: thx.  I'll use that for now until I can figure the 'unanswered' bit too.

Comment: @sfinnie: See the [search tips](http://stackoverflow.com/search) for a bit more.

Comment: @Georg: thx - will take a look there too.

Comment: @Tobias, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The `intags:mine` operator  [returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Applying this to @LanceRoberts answer:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+answers%3A0
```

But neither this, nor his suggested method, support sorting by date asked ☹

Edit: Martin Smith provided [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0), which will sort chronologically:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0
```

Thanks all!

Edit: Another improvement: [skip closed (and on hold) posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano
```

Comment: Click on the "newest" tab to get descending date order. URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0`