# URL for unanswered questions containing any one of tags, sorted by newest

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, search

I searched around meta but did not find an answer that fulfills what I'm looking for.

I would like to see a list that:

1. contains only unanswered questions
2. is sorted by newest first
3. each question matches one or more of a list of tags (that is, A or B or C).
4. can be accessed with a URL from stackoverflow.com

I tried [Stack Exchange filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/40703/my-css) which doesn't seem too flexible.

[This one came closest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64659/183395), but it searches questions containing both excel and vba. I don't know how to apply "OR" keyword instead. Simply inserting OR into the URL returns no results.

`https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[excel]%20[vba]%20answers%3a0`

[Works for excel and vba](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bexcel%5D%20%5Bvba%5D%20answers:0) and now [Broken when I naively add OR](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D%20or%20%5Bvba%5D%20answers:0&submit=search)

I also ran into something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%20or%20javascript but it is sorted by votes.
How can these two functionalities be joined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Easy enough to do](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/vba%20or%20excel?tab=newest).

You start with the main unanswered tab:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Then you filter out the tags you're interested in; instead of `/questions/tagged/x`, it'll be `/unanswered/tagged/x`. You can search for multiple tags by combining them with "or".

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/vba+or+excel

Then you sort by newest:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/vba+or+excel?tab=newest

Comment: Simple and brilliant! _Grazie!_