# Quick filter by favorites (tags)

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Would be great to be able to filter by favorite tags.

Comment: I don't think that is a dupe @PolyGeo as this is a FR for the App.  What you link to is how the feature works on the site which I assume the OP is familiar with and now requests to have that also in the App.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64651/how-to-search-for-unanswered-questions-in-my-tags-only-newest-first/213087#213087 may be related, but I'm not sure how applicable it is on the app.

Comment: @rene You're right.  The app wasn't mentioned in the question body or title and I had overlooked the tag.

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy `intags:mine` works on the app.

Comment: @rene unless I'm missing something, may I know the (deleted) dupe target and how to filter free search by favorite tags only? AFAIK, the web version only supports "unanswered question on my tags" per-site, which the app has also included it... unless it's a global filter on main SE page.

Comment: Both close votes are wrong, you missed the [tag:android-app] here. Found the real duplicate, but the other two stick. :/