# How can I filter "Newest Questions" based on my favourite tags?

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)

At the moment, when I click on "Newest Questions", those questions with a tag matching ANY one of my favourites are highlighted. However, that amounts only to 3 to 6 questions out of 30 in my case (sorry, I'm just not a generalist). Rather than have to add ALL of my favourite tags with "OR" manually, it would be great if there were a way to click on "favourites" and this happens automatically. That is, I want to filter out the Newest Questions based on ALL of my favourite tags.

If there is already a way to do this, please enlighten me. Otherwise, it seems like not such a hard thing to implement, right?

Comment: I raised this before, but was accused of being narrow-minded for not being able (not even necessarily uninterested) in looking at the Lord-knows how many 1000s of questions there are on StackExchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/is-there-a-way-to-sort-unanswered-my-tag-questions-by-date-newest-first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [tag set](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/) with your favourite tags to view multiple ones at the same time.

The request to have a tab for all questions with your interesting tags [has been denied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) in the past.

Comment: Yes, for one tag it's easy. The question is how to do this for multiple tags, or better, all of my favourite tags.

Comment: @PengOne See my updated answer.

Comment: The tag set is a good approximation. It's a shame the stackgods don't see this as a useful feature.