# Easy way to find newest unanswered question in a given tag

Tags: feature-request

When I go to stackexchange to answer questions, I want to be able to look at recent unanswered questions in certain tags.

I realize that there is the possibility to do this for the favourite tags via the main page (see [Is there a way to sort unanswered "my tag" questions by date, newest first?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/is-there-a-way-to-sort-unanswered-my-tag-questions-by-date-newest-first)) or to create a custom filter via the main page or via search expressions, but these solutions have several advantages:

Customs filters are a lot of work to do that always has to be redone for each new tag. The main page "favourite tags" solution mixes up all favourite tags from all sites, does it *only* for favourite tags and also loses the style of the individual sites.

> **What I want:** Menu options for choosing simultaneously a certain tag (ideally a set of them), unanswered and sorted by date.
>
> **Why do I want this?** My typical use of stackexchange: I have 10 minutes time, go to math.SE to answer some questions. I decide that it is a good day to answer, say, complex analysis questions, click on the respective tag and now can either look at active questions where I have to endlessly scroll and click to finally find an appropriate question at the end of my 10 minutes window. I leave. The most votes tab is almost totally useless to potential answerers, because the unanswered math questions that gather lots of votes are those that are easy to understand, but most likely do not have a good answer. The first page of this tab usually hardly changes at all over time.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://site.com/questions/tagged/mytag?sort=unanswered
```

In your case:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis?sort=unanswered

Comment: Actually, I have to retract my joy. It works when I click the URL, but when I then click on "unanswered" and get the vote-sorted unanswered list, the URL will then also give me the vote-sorted unanswered list. It really seems to depend on the last sorting or something. It is not a reliable method.

Comment: Yeah, clicking on any of the tabs is a "reset."  It has to be manipulated in the URL.

Comment: That's not what I mean. When I 1) go to your URL, it works 2) then click on unanswered, I get vote-sorted as usual 3) and then go to your URL again, it stays vote-sorted.

Comment: Well, there's also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis?sort=newest  I don't know if you can combine sorts or not, maybe this gets you close enough?

Comment: The point of this thread is that you cannot combine it.