# Way to show all the questions in "interesting tags"

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Currently the "Unanswered" tag (with the default view of "my tags") gives a list of unanswered questions with interesting tags. I'd like to see *all* questions matching my tags, not just unanswered ones.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Comment: The title on that one isn't particularly good, which is why I didn't find it. Thanks.