# Can we have a page with only questions about interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, tag-watching

I'm new to Stack Overflow, and I'm looking for a list of questions that contains just questions about interesting tags. For example, I'm interested in Java, and have no clue about Python, but questions about Python clutter my questions page. I don't have answers concerning any Python problem. I think it's too exhausting to enter my interesting tags in the search combined with OR. Is there a usable way to do this?

By the way, what are interesting tags used for right now? I added some in my profile but didn't see a benefit.

Comment: Check out this feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Comment: Are you Stefan, the Cherokee developer?

Answer (score 3):

If you're only interested in questions with a particular tag, I recommend browsing within that tag rather than the homepage.

It is possible to bring all your interesting tags into a tag set at http://stackexchange.com -- see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

You can also subscribe to them via RSS or email

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/

Answer (score 1):

As of right now the tag-searching mechanism is the only way of getting a list of only interesting-tags.

I do like this feature request though and I wouldn't think it'd be too hard to add another tab to the home page for My Tags or something like that.