# Possible to only view questions that are tagged with one of your "favorite tags"?

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a page with only questions about interesting tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51485/can-we-have-a-page-with-only-questions-about-interesting-tags)

Is there some way that I can only view questions that are tagged with one of my favorite tags?  If not, would people find this useful enough to be added as a new feature?

I find myself scanning questions for tags that are in my favorite tags quite often...

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Favorite Tags filter on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags): it allows you to view questions based on your favorite tags across the entire Stack Exchange network. You can also [create a new filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new) for more fine-grained control over which questions are shown.

The following links provide more detailed explanations of tag filters.

- [Tag Sets on Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/)
- [Is there a way to see questions with a certain tag from all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101905/is-there-a-way-to-see-questions-with-a-certain-tag-from-all-stack-exchange-sites/110281#110281)

Answer (score -1):

All of the questions that have your favorite tags are shaded differently than other. (Same goes for the ignored tags.)

Comment: And you can hide questions that are on your ignored list - go to "prefs" and click "hide ignored tags".