# A more interesting user specific unanswered feed

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, data-explorer

The unanswered question feed is kind of cool but it feels a tad general to me.

Can anybody think of a different query on data explorer that takes into account the tags I am good at answering and lists those unanswered questions first?

Comment: Remember to vote for this: [Interesting Tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

Comment: @Lance, Which also brings up a good point, I can do this kind of manually by adding interesting tags, but it would be cool to see an automatic query

Comment: After looking at SEDE, I see there are quite a few fields missing, including anything to tell what a user's interesting tags are.

Comment: @Lance, which fields ?

Comment: @waffles, I haven't looked at the actual database to know what the fields would be, but there isn't one for 'Interesting Tags' or 'Ignored Tags'.  There was something else I noticed wasn't there, but can't remember what it is right now.

Comment: @Lance true, perhaps we should add that to the data dump. Nonetheless you can get a full list of a users activity and work it out that way.

Comment: Hold on, there's an unanswered question feed?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/180/find-interesting-unanswered-questions

It takes into account your 20 most upvoted tags, question score and askers reputation.

You may want to play around with this line: 
`(sum(t.[Count]) / 10.0 + us.Reputation / 200.0 + p.Score * 100) as Weight`

Which can be used to determine the score.

I just ran it with my user id and got a very interesting list, which is much better for me (imho) that the current unanswered list.