# Any way to view posts matching my favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request

It would be convenient to have a feature so that I can only view questions that are related to tags of my interest. This way, I would not be shown any posts for which I do not have any knowledge.

Is there someway to do this already?

Comment: On the right-hand side there are "Interesting Tags" and "Ignored Tags" you can pick

Comment: See this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) for a feature-request.

Comment: I tried using interesting tags in stackoverflow.com. However, I don't see any filtering based on these. What is the need for interesting tag then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like a tab view, similar to the |Active|Featured|Hot|... but with a [MY TAGS] tab. I think that would be pretty terrific also, instead of needing to go through all of the tags individually.

Adding an RSS to that would make it amazing.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) for a feature-request.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the "best" option is to search for your tags of interest - `[foo] [bar] [baz]` - and bookmark it. However, you are limited to 20 or so tags, since the URL has a length limit.

Answer (score 0):

The Unanswered landmark defaults, afaik, to showing questions with no upvoted answers in the tags you have marked interesting.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags