# Filter only posts marked as interesting

Tags: support, search, tag-search

How can I view only the questions with tags I marked as interesting?

Comment: I agree on this. It would be helpful to me to view recent questions in my "interested" taglist. I can still look at the main "all" list in case qs of interest are mistagged.

Comment: @Steve: For unanswered ones see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/57564).

Answer (score 3):

> How can I view only the questions with tags I marked as interesting?

You can use the search box, just put brackets around your tag and press enter (for example: **[`[C#]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)**). **[There are many search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)**.

Or you can click on things:

1: **Simply click on the tag of interest in the upper right:**

---

[image]

---

2: **Use the tabs to sort the questions within that one tag**

---

[image]

---

3: **To further narrow the questions displayed using tags, click on a "related" tag (on the righ below the ads):**

---

[image]

---

4: **Now only tags displaying all of the selected tags will be shown:**

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click the **unanswered** button and select the **my tags** tab. For other questions you'll have to search for your tags individually:

```
[c#] [homework]
```

Comment: thanks :) pity this is this only available for unanswered posts

Comment: also very strange that most of the posts in unaswered tab are answered :)

Comment: @keshav - the SO definition of unanswered is "no upvoted answers". So a question might have 10 zero score answers and still be classed as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add on to Simon Browns answer:

> ```
> answers:0 [c#] [homework]
> ```

Gives you all the interesting tags w/ no answers which is quite useful for hunting down questions to answer. (Only because you said you found it strange that the unanswered tab had answers to the questions).

Comment: where can i find all the list of queries similar to what you posted just now, its not there in faq or about page