# URL with logical OR of tags

Tags: support, tags, hyperlinks

I am regular StackOverflow participant. Since I work mostly in C++, C, and python, I would like to read only those questions which are tagged with at least one of them.

I found that I can use

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++
```

for questions tagged with "c++".

How do I extend this to read questions tagged with

```
c++ OR c OR python
```

where OR is logical-OR?

I tried

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++ + c + python
```

but it seems that the '+' in the URL is doing logical-AND and that is not what I want.

[I would not be surprised if this question turns out to be duplicate, but in my search, I could not find the answer.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++ or c or python" works.

Btw: It's not the `+` that causes the and. Simply using "tagged/c++ c python" will have the same effect as the url you tried. The `+` is simply ignored.

Comment: Wow! I never tried using the 'or' in the URL.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be *partially* useful, adding "checkboxen" and a "show only" button to allow filtering of the current question "view" on a subset of tags:
[image] 
To allow question filtering on multiple tags.

**PRO**
Helps narrow down to some good answers in a subset of tags

**CON**
May stop people bumping into mis-tagged questions and correcting them. Sort of boxes people into subjects which I don't like.

**My vote: Meh**

Comment: Related: this answer by Jeff for a related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/63947#63947