# Reading posts with my favorite tags only

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

I, like many other stackoverflow.com users, created the 'Interesting Tags' list. How can I browse post with those tags (with all of them) only?

Comment: Belongs on meta?

Comment: i.e. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab for interesting questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

Comment: @Lance Roberts, it is! Can't believe they refused this feature...

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see this, too.

Of course, posts tagged with tags you're "interested" in are highlighted and those you're "not interested" in are grayed out. But this seems insufficient at times. For example, if I'm in the mood to troll for C++ questions, how does one do this without wading through seas of pythons and grails?

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this on http://stackexchange.com using tagged question sets.