# Hide non-favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm only interested in certain subjects on StackOverflow. I don't want to see every post about Cocoa/vb.net/random technology. Can we have the option to hide all tags not specified as favorites? My ignore list is growing unwieldy, while my favorites list remains small:

```
# favorites
jquery python lisp artificial-intelligence machine-learning 
# ignored
java c# c++ java-me iphone android asp.net php drupal .net xml cocoa tinymce clearcase verilog libc oracle matlab vb.net dreamweaver silverlight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is going to get implemented.

I would suggest you:

- use the main [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) homepage which is filtered to your favourite tags (90% favourite tags and 10% random)
- use the [cross site tag sets on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) to filter question based on the tags you provide.
- simply browse questions by their individual tags on Stack Overflow e.g [browse only sql-server questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)

This is Jeffs response to [this previous question on this matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11563/148203):

> We believe that browsing by tag, and
> tag combination, should be sufficient.
> The bleedthrough and forced exposure
> to other topics is intentional; we
> believe programmers have more in
> common across languages and
> disciplines than they think they do.
> We don't want to create more "ghettos"
> where programmers only care about or
> look at certain pet topics.
>
> Good programmers are well-rounded, and
> are aware of the world outside their
> "special preferred" tag.

[Answer is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions/63947#63947)

Comment: I hate the paternalism in Jeff's response, but I suppose it'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

The [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) is showing any question with favorite tags marked with different color, which IMO is good enough to distinguish.

I think that completely hiding all other questions is mistake - sometimes you'll be surprised to see something you can answer tagged with irrelevant tag for example sometimes `ASP.NET` question also involve jQuery and the solution is pure `jQuery` although the OP didn't add that tag.

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

You can pull your favorite tags into a tag set and view them there, or have them emailed to you.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here seem to imply that the average programmer can answer some reasonable percentage of the questions they see, i.e., more than 10%. That's not true. There are 70k unanswered questions SO for C#. I probably only have good answers for a few dozen of those.

I don't think that the requested feature would need to be persisted. I would like a list of tags on the page that can be hidden for three hours. Maybe I'm not in the mood to research questions about windows-phone today. I want to hide all posts with that tag for some small period just to quickly narrow down the list to questions that I have time to answer. You would get more answers if I didn't have to weed through 70k questions that I can't answer.