# Show only questions related with my favorite tags

Tags: support, tag-watching, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab for questions that are labelled with interesting or favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labelled-with-interesting-or-favorite-tags)

How can I do so that in "all questions". I want to see only the questions that include my favorite tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) on StackExchange.com.

Comment: is it possible there to use several tags?

Comment: @user: Yes; try it.

Comment: I mean, how? I can only add one at the moment, the first is recognized, but not the others