# Where can I find the "Interesting" tab

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

I just logged into SO on a computer I don't normally use, and after login, the page was showing only questions with my tags, and there was a tab "Interesting" highlighted. Judging from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labelled-with-interesting-or-favorite-tags) and others, there is no such tab, but there it was!

Is there any way of getting to that tab other than logging in on a new machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "interesting" tab is visible on the home page of Stack Overflow, and it shows the questions using one of the tags you added in your favorite list, and other questions you could find interesting; the system decides which questions you could find interesting basing on the questions you previously watched, or the ones you previously answered.

[image: screenshot]

When you are logged out, the "interesting" tab is still shown, but the shown questions are not "personalized."

[image: screenshot]

To get to that page, just go to stackoverflow.com (not stackoverflow.com/questions), and select the "interesting" tab, if it is not already selected.

Answer (score 3):

Just click on the name **stackoverflow** below the logo at the top left of the screen.

It's a link to the home page mentioned by [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno)

It works if you're logged-in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I was close to ask where to find it after I clicked somewhere else. Because then it is gone and invisible.

Answer (score 1):

There are all questions, but yours favourite are higlighted. 
It's classic feature of SO, and it does not matter what PC you're on.