# More questions like the ones in the Interesting tab

Tags: discussion, interesting-page

It could be just my perception, but I seem to find a lot more questions that I want to look at in the Interesting tab (on Stack Overflow) than I do by just browsing (despite the fact that I have many tags which I ignore and many that I follow).

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98719/interesting-tab), the system populates the Interesting tab based on your favourite tags as well as questions you've answered before, etc. This is great, but the issue I have is the fact that the Interesting tab is only ever one page. You can't get to a second or third page of interesting questions as far as I can tell.

So, my question is this: Is there any way to get more than one page of questions such as the ones you would normally see in the Interesting tab? Perhaps a particular combination of search options?

Comment: "I seem to find a lot more questions that I want to look at in the Interesting tab (in Stackoverflow) than I do by just browsing". Weird how that works :)

Comment: Haha, fair point, although I did qualify that with the fact that I've ignored a great number of tags, so there is obviously more to the Interesting tab than just questions from your favorite tags.