# User setting for Tag Priority

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, interesting-page

While I have only 11 favorite tags, some of them get a lot of traffic, while some are more niche tags.  I usually hang out on Stack Overflow in the Interesting page, but I've found that by time I see the niche tag questions on there (which are the ones I'm best equipped to answer), they already have a few answers.

Could we get a way to set a priority on our Favorite Tags, just so that the Interesting page algorithm will take that into account when listing questions?

Answer (score 3):

+1 I like this suggestion.

As for an implementation of setting this priority: dragging the tags around could suffice. Although the favorited tag list appears on almost any page, maybe this functionality should be added only to the */prefs* tab on the user profile page, so all other pages do not need load the script.

The more tricky part is *how* to take that priority into account? Any solution will break the default sorting order, won't it? But since the interesting page is personalized anyway, maybe that is not a great problem.

I noticed that the interesting tab is just one page, contains 90 items and goes (as of now) about 5 hours back in time. *(What is the average time frame?)* The driving algorithm already filters questions based on your favorite list, questions you previously watched and the ones you previously answerered ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98719/interesting-tab/98720#98720)).

I think the new algorithm should not reorder just that same 90 items, but instead it must pick a whole different set of items in order to take the priority into account. I think it will be a combination of the new priority index, the age, and the currently running algorithm.