# Why can't I see my question on the front page 5 minutes after it was posted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, homepage

Here's the question: [How to split tasks between CI Tool (like Jenkins) and a build script (Ant or Maven)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113427/how-to-split-tasks-between-ci-tool-like-jenkins-and-a-build-script-ant-or-mav)

I haven't seen it yet on the front page. Why is it that?

Comment: The `front page` is heavily cached. I would say this is by design, not a bug.

Comment: @slhck: it disappeared again :(((

Comment: And I was just wondering why you keep adding 3 spaces in the edits (2 yet). I saw it at the frontpage the whole time (due to my tags presumably)

Comment: @örs That kind of behavior is ***definitely*** frowned upon (artificlally editing one's post just to bump it to the front page, that is).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "main board"? If you're referring to the (default) [Interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) questions page - that page is weighted toward your Favorite Tags, so if you're not following your question's tags, you may not see it as frequently. It should, however, appear on the [Newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) questions page right after being asked.

Comment: @Rob Hruska: stackoverflow.com

Comment: A 12k which is bumping his question? `oO'`

Comment: I would say if you are performing edits with zero impact (not even trivial) like this to try and *bump*, don't be surprised if a) the question is deleted with extreme prejudice and b) if you do it often, moderator action is taken.

Comment: @Bobby: I was trying to get why it's not seen to me.

Comment: @Roman: In that case you should have used a meaningful edit-message.

Comment: given SO traffic, I'd rather be surprised if I **could** see my question on the front page 5 minutes after it was posted

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about the Home Page, the one you reach by going to https://stackoverflow.com/ then it is very heavily cached. You won't see updates almost immediately. Eventually you should see it change, however, if it never does, then you should inform the team about it - that's when it might be a bug. What your seeing is by design.

Don't expect the home page to always [be exactly in order](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4087/80670), and refresh constantly. [The Newest Questions page is easier to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). Patience is a virtue.

On another note, don't keep adding random spaces to your post and try to bump it - You'll end up having your post deleted if anything. You do have 12k rep, I think you might know this by now.

Comment: see my comment to Bobby. I didn't know that the front page shows questions set depending on my favorite tags. And that's why it looked really weird to me why I cannot find my own question, while I didn't have this problem before (since the most of my questions was tagged with favorited tags and this one is not).

Answer (score 1):

The main page (i.e. [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)) is your Interesting questions, which is based heavily on your Favorite Tags. Are you following any of the tags that your question is using?

[Where can I find the "Interesting" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98719/interesting-tab)

If not, your question should appear in the [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) questions list almost immediately after being posted.