# Interesting tab shows "uninteresting" questions

Tags: bug, interesting-page

The [Interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) mostly shows questions tagged with my Favourite Tags. However, it also shows the odd question *not* tagged with one of my Favourites Tags.

It seems very unintuitive behaviour to me; a little like if we were to include questions with no bounty on the [Featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab.

See the screen grab below for an example: questions tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid) are appearing even though I have neither of those tags in my list of favourites.

Is this a bug, or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

[image]

Comment: I think it shows questions based on what you've viewed as well

Comment: Thanks guys. In my case I wonder if I'm seeing jquery questions because I've viewed .net questions also containing the jquery tag. Irritating behavior if that's the case, to me anyway.

Comment: Yeah, AI isn't that good yet. I think that falls under the rubric of "making the site more awesome", so I'm convinced that the team is working hard on it.

Comment: @razlebe Done. I had expected this to be closed by now. But there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98719/interesting-tab):

> "The "interesting" tab is visible on the home page of Stack Overflow, and it shows the questions using one of the tags you added in your favorite list, **and other questions you could find interesting**"

So yes, it should predominantly show questions you're actually interested in, but will most likely also show the odd question related to tags you've somehow visited.