# View hot questions within a particular tag

Tags: discussion, tags, hot-questions

Should it be possible to view hot questions within your favorite tag?

Currently, the "Interesting" tab only features half a dozen questions in my favorite tag (Ruby), and the "Hot" tab only features two questions in my favorite tag.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-interesting-tags