# Feature Request - Multiple selection of selectors

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, filtering

I am a regular user of SO and other stack sites. and found it can be better if we can have some functionality like choosing unanswered questions which are of mytags and are newest..

I mean we have filters over there which filters question based on one thing either `mytags`, `newest`, `votes`, `unanswered`. there should be multiple selection which filters a lower deeper for say newest with mytags.

and also while selecting by votes it can have range of votes to chose from..

I hope this feature will make it more user friendly.

Comment: See this [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-interesting-tags) for one option, which could then be filtered with a button one more level, like newest.

Comment: i guess that request was for `mytags`  thing i am asking 1 more level deep. clubbing my tags with recent first and letting user combine 2-3 options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would complicate the site for *most* users while actually improving the experience for a very *few*.  We want as little complication in the UI as possible, especially smaller sites (which we try to keep the UI in line with) where this makes almost no sense given the volume.

Answer (score 0):

For your first qustion you can use the url. Try something like:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/html+or+css

And hit the "Newest" tab.

For the votes part you can use `votes` in the url to select a minimum of votes, not a range (see https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the things been said are an alternative and the things i said will make using Stack sites easy for the users