# list all questions that have any of my tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)

I just added a bunch of tags to my account at the scifi exchange.

Is there a way to see all of the questions that have any of my tags?

I have 11 tags there already, so it's a pain to page through the list of all questions with the next button.

thanks

Comment: Is this what you want?: http://stackexchange.com/ -> tagged questions -> my filters

Comment: @Ray well? Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What are you referring to with *"page through the list of all questions with the next button"*? That's just the regular "All questions" page, right? (I'm a bit confused by your *"I have 11 tags there already"*, which kind of tells me you expect to have to click even more when you add more tags. But that's unrelated, I assume.)

Comment: @arjan no, i was referring to paging through search results or going through all questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can search questions that have ***tag1*** AND ***tag2*** by using: `.../questions/tagged/tag1 tag2`
or you can search questions that have ***tag1*** OR ***tag2***:
`.../questions/tagged/tag1 or tag2` 
or combinations of both are also supported.

If you want to avoid typing, bookmark page with this "search query" of yours ;)