# Link on top of Favorite Tags which can browse me through all questions tagged with my Fav tags?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [list all questions that have any of my tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122484/list-all-questions-that-have-any-of-my-tags)

I know that we can achieve similar functionality by searching though multiple tags but having a link to browse all questions having fav tags will be great.

Another problem with current approach is that when you search by multiple tags you get result with AND join and with link I am talking about we can provide OR result. Meaning that if my favorite tags are PHP and MYSQL I can see questions falling under either of them.

Comment: And possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags