# Is there a way to sort favorite tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-watching

I was looking at my tags list today and thought that if it was extremely long I might like to find them to view their corresponding questions.

Is there a way to sort your favorite tags yourself, most votes, most questions in that area, etc?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the edit! Apparently I don't know the differences between their, there, and they're.

Comment: no worries, it's a common mistake. I catch myself sometimes too - I seem to be better at spotting it when someone else has done it.

Comment: This could be a fun little stackapps project for somebody, easily doable as a browser extension, Greasemonkey script, Google Chrome user script, etc.

Comment: Huh, good idea I might take this upon consideration. Thanks

Comment: I came here looking for similar functionality - I'm interested in drag/drop to re-sort the favorite tags list. I may start work on a userscript for it.

Comment: @meta.michael I haven't started work on it, if you do let me know how it works out?

Comment: @Nate Actually, I'm just finishing it up. I have it in github but not yet on stackapps.com.  The Chrome extension version is more polished than the Firefox userscript... https://github.com/mberkowski/se-sortable-tags

Comment: @Nate It isn't too well tested yet, but when I feel better about it I'll post to stackapps.

Comment: @meta.michael ah aright I'll take a look at it. Will let you know if I find any bugs

Comment: @meta.michael It's really nice, only thing I found I couldn't do was edit the order under preferences on my profile page.

Comment: @Nate Honestly I didn't even know that was there. I can't remember going to that prefs page since I joined SE years ago. If you're using the Chrome version, I just pushed a new manifest.json to github which enables it for /users/preferences*

Comment: @meta.michael Yea I just remembered it was there! When you do post this to stackapps you can also post an answer to this to link them up.

Comment: @meta.michael:  I will check Stack Apps and/or GitHub when I get time later, but did you follow with a post to SA?  I don't see a follow-up to Nate's previous comment - an answer to this question to link to your follow-on SA post if so.  Thanks.

Comment: @J0e3gan I never did get it onto SA, owing to the fact that shortly after I completed it, they made modifications to the tag lists which include some of my functionality (the delete button hiding, but not the sorting).  when I get time, I'll update my extension to work with it...

Comment: I'd really like having favorite tags sorted alphabetically by default. A bonus would be to give them a custom order, but that would be secondary in my wish list.