# Customisable default questions page

Tags: feature-request, questions, tag-watching

When I go to view questions on Stack Overflow I find that there are many questions with tags that I know nothing about. So of course I start filtering the questions by tags from my favourites.

It would be nice if I could set my default questions page to only show questions which contain at least one of my favourite tags.

I realise there's an advanced search facility that I could use but I don't think it accepts any kind of 'or' like syntax. For example, a search for tags [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) will only return questions that have all three of those tags. What I really want is to see all questions which contain one or more of those tags, and to be able to set this as my default 'Questions' page.

Comment: damn, couldn't find this at the time of writing but it's basically a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Comment: There's also the "Interesting" questions list, which may be closer to what you're looking for. Click on the StackOverflow link to the left of the Questions tab; most of the questions should either be those you've listed as favourites or those you've been active in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom built URL (and bookmark/favourite it) to express your tag preferences using OR:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree+OR+queue
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree+java+OR+queue+python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree+java+OR+queue+python+OR+django+OR+haskell

It can cope perfectly well with quite a few of these, at speed.

Credit: tidied up version of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61310/194906).

Comment: Yes, I use `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+html+or+css+or+javascript+or+jquery+or+actionscript-3+or+ruby+or+regex+or+python` and it loads almost instantly `:D`