# Let us filter the normal questions list by favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

> **Possibly not a duplicate:**
> [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)
> <sup>(refer to end of post to see why)</sup>

Currently, to view a feed of all questions tagged with my favorite tags, I have a bookmark in my browser, which is: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+html+or+css+or+javascript+or+jquery+or+actionscript-3+or+ruby+or+regex+or+python` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+html+or+css+or+javascript+or+jquery+or+actionscript-3+or+ruby+or+regex+or+python))

Now, I have a few problems with this:

- It doesn't update when I change my favorite tags
- I can only access it from *my* computer

I searched around a bit and found [this filter thing](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags?sort=newest), which supposedly gives you questions tagged with your favorite tags across SE, but:

- It seems to be bugged; [I only see questions from gamedev.SE in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx7pF.png)
- I can't choose which site I want to see questions from
- It doesn't update in real time (that "1 new question, click to load" thing)

There's also [the Unanswered tab, which has a "my tags" category](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags), but there are problems with it as well:

- You can only see questions with no answers (of course)
- The only way you can sort it is by votes (not newest)
- It doesn't update in real time

---

So, could we please get a "my tags" filter? I'm thinking something like either of these:
[image]

I personally like option B more. <sup>(for future reference, [here's how I made that checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXHjn.png))</sup>

---

**NOTE**: This is not a duplicate of [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags). I am not requesting a tab, but I am requesting that we keep the same tabs we have now, but we add a "favorite tags" checkbox/option.

Comment: Yes, searching for `[c++] or [c++11] or [algorithm] or ...` is no fun.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense to me. I've always thought the "hide ignored tags" thing was a bit backwards. There are far more tags I'm *not* interested in than tags I *am* interested in. Even with the wildcards, there's no way I can build up a comprehensive list of tags to ignore. It's not that difficult to build up a comprehensive list of "favorite" tags.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Question Lists!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179) (Currently only available on Stack Overflow, its meta, and here, plus you have to opt into it in your profile.)

As you can see here, "My watched tags" does exactly what you want:

> [image]

Soon you will be able to save this as left sidebar thing, so I'd argue that this question kinda sorta might be a dupe D: