# Unified personal homepage for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, homepage

I think it would be useful to have a unified homepage that displays a tailed set of questions (based on the user logged in) from across the range of stack exchange sites.

Something like a cross between the existing [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com/) homepage that lists top questions from all sites, and an individual site homepage that allows you to pick to sort questions by active/hot/unanswered/newest/votes/mytags etc.

Edit: As suggested by [Lord.Quackstar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60650/unified-personal-hompage-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/60658#60658) an RSS feed of the unified personal question list would be good too.

<sub>Background:
My usage of SO goes like this. When I have 2 minutes free I hit the unanswered page sorted by newest and check the top 5-10 questions. If one looks interesting I'll take a look. Since stack exchange sites have started to become active I now have to check SO, SU, Meta, Photography and Ubuntu, and sometimes PhotoMeta and UbuntuMeta.</sub>

What I would like is to go to one page and for it to show the newest unanswered questions from the sites I am active on. Possibly including optional filtering by tags (but for established sites like SO, I would want tag filtering, but for new sites like Photography I still want to see all questions as I haven't built up a good tag list yet as it's still stabilising).

Comment: I agree, keeping track of what is happening on the 6 sites I'm active on is getting really hard, we do plan to make this easier

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11014

Answer (score 3):

This is possible on http://stackexchange.com

as documented in

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me following SO, SU, and this Meta is hard enough, and I only sometimes check the Ubuntu or Serverfault sites.

As pulling off a single master list correctly would be difficult, it would be nice if there were tabs for each of the sites. This way if the main feed becomes just a garbled mess, we can still follow individual sites from 1 interface. Each tab should be like the front page of the site, where you can sort by tags, newest, votes, etc.

While were on this topic, it should also include the unified message bar that's been talked about several times. And can it be a RSS feed please? I get tired of checking 6 sites just to see if I have any responses

Comment: +1 for the unified RSS feed suggestion.

Comment: +1 from me for the RSS feed, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like a unified login -- if I'm logged into to one site, please automatically log me into all of my active sites.

Comment: that is implemented, see [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)