# Many SE -> troubles keeping updated

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

As I subscribe and perform activities on different SE, I start to have a problem remembering where my questions and answers were, to follow up any comment I leave (if they get answers) and in general integrating my activity across the whole SE community.

I feel like the next important feature to add is a personal page, maybe on stackexchange.com after login, where the user is kept updated on things happening on a SE community-wide level.

Just a thought.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11014

Answer (score 4):

Such a dashboard would be helpful. Plus, a public version would allow me to link to something like https://stackexchange.com/users/####/user-name and allow people to see my profile, my reputation on all of the stack exchanges I participate in, and have quick access to the questions I ask and answer.

Comment: A tool similar to this exists below.

Comment: This is a nice tool, but if I link to a page on my personal site, I don't want to link to a third party site. I want to link to an official Stack Exchange page. Perhaps the SE staff can buy this from the original creator and incorporate it into the Stack Exchange site or create a new version of it (not sure what laws apply here or what the terms of the Stack Apps contest were).

Answer (score 1):

Login to [StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com) website. From here you can track all of your StackExchange accounts.

> StackCenter is a website designed to
>   make keeping track of all your
>   accounts easier. Simply enter your
>   username from one of the sites and
>   you're good to go! You can then view
>   your personal page that lists recent
>   comments to you, overall reputation,
>   etc. all on one page.
>
> As a new feature, I added a global
>   reputation graph for the last 30 days
>   so you can see how you're doing.
>
> **Source:** [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange)

[image: StackCenter]

Comment: This is a nice tool, but if I link to a page on my personal site as I mentioned in my post, I don't want to link to a third party site. I want to link to an official Stack Exchange page. Perhaps the SE staff can buy this from the original creator and incorporate it into the Stack Exchange site or create a new version of it (not sure what laws apply here or what the terms of the Stack Apps contest were)