# I Ask, and then I Forget

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange

With a proliferation of SE sites ( coupled with the original SOFU sites), I have a lot of places where I can ask my questions.

But this also means that unfortunately my QA histories are scattered around different sites, and I always forget to come back to provide the continuing interaction needed. With limited time and energy, I can only check SO on a daily basis. So invariably other less heavily used sites will be forgotten.

Is there anyway to solve this issue? Maybe there is a central site that show all my recent activities on SE+SOFU+meta sites?

P/S: if you don't see me active on this question you can safely assume that I've forgotten about it after asking. Talk about the irony :)

P/S2: Since I don't want SE to spam my email, so I won't check the Send email option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create one page on SE to show my notifications for all SE, etc sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/create-one-page-on-se-to-show-my-notifications-for-all-se-etc-sites)

Comment: another one : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61005/many-se-troubles-keeping-updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now complete.

1. look for the small indicator on the Stack Exchange logo in the upper right
2. click it to expand a list of network-wide replies to you.

[image: global inbox]

Comment: One odd thing about the global inbox is that it is more responsible than the envelope — it shows ❶ (correctly) before the envelope lights up! I don't know if this is a good news or not :)

Answer (score 3):

Login to [StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com) website. From here you can track all of your StackExchange accounts.

> StackCenter is a website designed to
>   make keeping track of all your
>   accounts easier. Simply enter your
>   username from one of the sites and
>   you're good to go! You can then view
>   your personal page that lists recent
>   comments to you, overall reputation,
>   etc. all on one page.
>
> As a new feature, I added a global
>   reputation graph for the last 30 days
>   so you can see how you're doing.
>
> **Source:** [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange)

[image: StackCenter]

Comment: +1 I like StackCenter. (And I'm not just saying that 'cuz I wrote it.)

Comment: Although this is good, not the data is not up to date all the time.

Comment: StackCenter uses StackExchange API 1.0. If data is not up to date then you can complain for that in StackApps (http://stackapps.com).

Comment: It displays a white screen with nothing in it after selecting my username!!

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, there is [Stack Overflow Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djioipahfnmmhddmnanoicecpnfomned), which also works on SE 1 sites.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Bonus feature: get Enthusiast and Fanatic badges much easier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like an RSS feed / Web Service by UserID would solve a problem like this. I think the op has got a very good point. I have found myself doing the same thing.