# Include all "recent activity" for all SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, recent-activity, global-inbox

The new [SE-network-wide reply notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45708/54262) is great, but could we have a single place to view all ["recent activity"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/how-do-i-view-my-recent-replies/45709#45709)?  Could be integrated with the reply notification, but wouldn't have to be.

Something that listed there was *some* new activity to view instead of listing what that exactly is (i.e. no need to include full text of anything), but still listed the site and what type of activity (e.g. I may not be interested in reputation, but would be in revisions) would be useful.

Comment: The new feature is a big improvement, so I almost feel bad asking for more... just no pleasing some people.

Comment: @Gnome: If there's enough interest, I may add that capability to [StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com).

Comment: @George: It is already available through [scraping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61352/i-ask-and-then-i-forget/65595#65595), and probably through the API too?  I find it useful, in any case.

Comment: Oh, duh, to scrape you have to be logged in, as the linked browser extension can be, so that wouldn't work for your site.

Comment: @Gnome: It sure would. All the information you're asking for is available with the API.

Answer (score 1):

This is coming later this week, perhaps by Thursday -- check your http://stackexchange.com profile page.

Completed per

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/